# adjust the url when fetching data in vue.js component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fetch-api

So i am trying to fetch data in my vue component  as you can see below. But because iam reqesting the fetch from my blade view in public/manage-users-projects the url becomes

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjsiteWebApp/app/public/manage-users-projects/get-projects-json
```

but i want to fetch data from this url

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjsiteWebApp/app/public/get-projects-json
```

So i can i sort of return one route and execute from the public folder?

```
export default {


    created(){
        this.fetchProjects();
    },


    methods:{
        fetchProjects() {
            fetch('get-projects-json')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                })
        }
    }
    
    

};






Route::get('get-projects-json', 'ProjectsController@getProjectsJson');
```

Comment: Why is this part of route needed: "ProjsiteWebApp/app/public" ? did you add it on purpose as a prefix ?

Comment: that is the exact url that the fetch methods calls on based on my parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the route as props to the component inside the blade file.

Inside the view:

```
<component get-projects-json="{{ url('get-projects-json') }}"></component>
```

Inside the vue component:

```
<script> 
    export default {
        props: ['getProjectsJson'],
    }
</script>
```

Then you can access the route inside the component like so:

```
export default {


    created(){
        this.fetchProjects();
    },


    methods:{
        fetchProjects() {
            fetch(this.getProjectsJson)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                })
        }
    }
    
    

};
```

You can learn more about props here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html